# Python error: Invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the code and the output. I assume is it about the score not being int, but not sure how to convert in this case

[image: The code and the output]

```
df.index = df.columns
rows = []
for i in df.index:
    for c in df.columns:
        if i == c: continue
        score = df.ix[i, c]
        score = [int(row) for row in score.split('-')]
        rows.append([i, c, score[0], score[1]])
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = ['home', 'away', 'home_score', 'away_score'])
df.head()
```

Comment: You shouldn't paste screenshots of code but the actual code text itself

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy he is using score.split("-") though

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy, thanks, still an error. slightly different though, just '-' left in the tail of the error

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the character is not really '-'...

Comment: @hobbs answer below explains what might be happening. Simple solution is this: `[int(row) for row in score if row.isnumeric()]`

Answer (score 3):

You're splitting on "-" (U+0020 `HYPHEN-MINUS`), but your data is using some other character... it's hard to say since you provided a *picture* of the error instead of the actual error, but it's probably "–" (U+2013 `EN DASH`). Fix your split to use the character that actually occurs in the input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just do

```
score = [int(row) for row in score if row.isnumeric()]
```

Take advantage of the `.isnumeric()` method of strings.

P.S. You should not be using `.ix` method with Pandas. I am pretty sure it is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

The screenshot you posted is identifying the issue.  You are trying to call `int()` on the `str` `0-3`.  This can't be done.  From my terminal

```py
In [1]: int('0-3')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c6bc87cd2bc7> in <module>
----> 1 int('0-3')

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0-3'
```

Looking at your dataframe it looks like you have a lot of data that can't be turned into an `int` as is

Comment: he is using `score.split("-")` though

Comment: Not correctly.  The the error output clearly shows he's trying to turn `'0-3'` into an `int`.  He's not actually splitting that string.  The `row` variable there isn't the string from the actual row

Comment: yeah I understand, and he knows that. His question is how to convert it, not what the problem is.

Comment: Not sure that that's the case based on the question title...Also if he wants to know how to convert `0-3` to an integer he needs to give more instruction on what he expects that behavior to be.  The code he's using is overwriting the same `df` variable and he hasn't pasted in any data for anyone else to reproduce it

Comment: @sedavidw Look at Hobbs' answer.  He got it right.  OP's code is correct.  He is just not splitting by the correct hyphen character.